# Notify the UI Thread from Background Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to download some pages in the background, whose contents will be inserted into a database.

I need to do this on a background thread of some kind (either BackgroundWorker or ThreadPool, which is preferred due to the way I can queue things up), but I also need to update the UI when the jobs are done.

How can I notify the UI thread that the jobs are finished on Windows Phone?

I've seen someone use Dispatcher.beginInvoke, but it wasn't clear what he was using (either Worker or Pool)-- is this the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
 Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
 {
      // change UI here
 });
```

[Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) allows you to run a piece of code on a thread.

[Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.deployment%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class provides the application information of a silverlight-based application.

this is the code you need to use, actually this is the way you can run a piece of code on UI thread from another thread (no matter how and where that thread is running).

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you're using MVVM, you could update the viewmodel off the UI thread and let the magic of INotifyPropertyChanged handle updating the UI for you.