# wpf background load

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I'm using a WindowsFormsHost to load into a 3d render object.

in fact I took the handle from it.

my problem is that I wish create some loading screen or similar, but only using a backgroundworker, when I access to my WindowsFormsHost properties (reading, height, width and handle), the thread raise an exception..

how can I solve this thing?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862590/how-to-update-gui-with-backgroundworker) apply to you? If not please describe what exception?

Comment: Yep, check Jacob link, this is probably just a thread error. You cannot update UI from a background Thread, but you can call the UI thread from background to perform the update.

Comment: thanks @Ouarzy, how can I call the UI thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update the UI thread as explain in this post: [Notify the UI Thread from Background Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750145/notify-the-ui-thread-from-background-thread)

Roughly: you just need a dispatcher.BeginInvoke (for an async call) on the UI thread.