# Why binding is not enough to refresh UI in WP7 (MVVM)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm

I'm trying to create WP7 application based on MVVM pattern but I have problem with refreshing bind content of TextBlock. **In the current state I need to reopen page to refresh content.** I think that it's related to setting data context but I couldn't fix it.

**PropertyChangedEventHandler in ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string _txtStatus = "";
    public string TxtStatus
    {
        get { return _txtStatus; }
        set
        {
            _txtStatus = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TxtStatus");
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel Property in App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static ViewModel _viewModel { get; set; }
    public static ViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return _viewModel ?? (_viewModel = new ViewModel()); }
    }
```

**Setting DataContext in StatusPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Status : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Status()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
    }
```

**Binding in StatusPage.xaml**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TxtStatus" Text="{Binding Path=TxtStatus, Mode=OneWay}" Width="450" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

**UPDATE 1**

**Setting value of TxtStatus in MqttService.cs**

```
public class MqttService
{
    private readonly ViewModel _viewModel;

    public MqttService(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    private void Log(string log)
    {
        _viewModel.TxtStatus = _viewModel.TxtStatus + log;
    }

    private void Connect()
    {
        _client.Connect(true);
        Log(MsgConnected + _viewModel.TxtBrokerUrl + ", " + _viewModel.TxtClientId + "\n");
        _viewModel.IsConnected = true;
    }
```

**MqttService Property in ViewModel.cs**

```
    private MqttService _mqttService;
    public MqttService MqttService
    {
        get { return _mqttService ?? (_mqttService = new MqttService(this)); }
    }
```

Now I wonder if maybe I have some kind of the circular reference problem (MqttService-ViewModel). I'm not sure, it looks good to me.

Comment: Are there any binding errors in the output view?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. How are you updating the value to be displayed in the textblock?

Comment: maybe you could add an `, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

Comment: @WiiMaxx this an OneWay textblock binding, UpdateSourceTrigger will never happen, because textblock cannot update the source

Comment: @blindmeis ah ok, i thought it will also something with the binding part from the Property to the View

Comment: @Erno de Weerd Could it be the problem? Content is current when I reopen the page, so binding Path is correct. But of course I'll check it later, now I don't have access to VS.

Comment: Is there some multi-threading in your application? More specifically, is `TxtStatus` updated in the UI thread?

Comment: You could set a breakpoint in the setter of the TxtStatus on the ViewModel and see whether or not it gets hit when you update the property. If it gets hit you might have 2 concurrent ViewModels; one attached to the View and one in the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You all. After [Erno de Weerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563088/erno-de-weerd) and [ken2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870604/ken2k) wrote comments about threads I did some research and found this: [Notify the UI Thread from Background Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750145/notify-the-ui-thread-from-background-). I changed the way of setting value of the TxtStatus and it's working perfectly now. :)

**(bad) Setting value of TxtStatus in MqttService.cs**

```
private void Log(string log)
{
    _viewModel.TxtStatus = _viewModel.TxtStatus + log;
}
```

**(good) Setting value of TxtStatus in MqttService.cs**

```
private void Log(string log)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        App.ViewModel.TxtStatus = log + App.ViewModel.TxtStatus;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me  in `WPF` `.NET4.0`

so maybe your Property `TxtStatus` never get a string

```
_txtStatus ="new status"; // wrong
TxtStatus = "new status"; // right
```

or you get some interfering with your `x:Name="TxtStatus"` but that would be an Windows-Phone-7 based problem